# Error: File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd

Tags: errors, resize

There are a few questions which deal with this already, but after having incorporated all the previous answers into my tex file, it still won't compile. Any help, much appreciated.

Edit: Added all the preamble etc now. Thank you for your time. 
Edit: Also this has been working fine, then when I opened up the file today, nothing would work!

```
\documentclass[twoside,fontsize=12pt,
 bibliography=totoc, 
 listof=totoc, 
 index=totoc,
 onehalfspacing]

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[labelfont=footnotesize,textfont=footnotesize]{caption}   
\usepackage{_twoopt}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[]{_EuroMasterDiss_sty}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{rotmat}
\resizebox{.915\hsize}{!}{%
\begin{array}{ccc}
R_{x}\left(\theta\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0 \\ 
0&\cos\theta&\sin\theta \\
0&-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\\
\end{array} 
\right),
\ \ \
& R_{y}\left(\theta\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta&0&-\sin\theta\\ 
0&1&0 \\
\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta\\
\end{array} 
\right),
\ \ \
& R_{z}\left(\theta\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta&\sin\theta&0 \\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{array}%
} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: So the working script looks like (note the additional dollar signs within the argument for \resizebox):

```
\documentclass[twoside,fontsize=12pt,
bibliography=totoc, 
listof=totoc, 
index=totoc,
onehalfspacing]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[labelfont=footnotesize,textfont=footnotesize]{caption}   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{rotmat}
\resizebox{.915\hsize}{!}{%
$\begin{array}{ccc}
R_{x}\left(\theta\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0 \\ 
0&\cos\theta&\sin\theta \\
0&-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\\
\end{array} 
\right),
\ \ \
& R_{y}\left(\theta\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta&0&-\sin\theta\\ 
0&1&0 \\
\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta\\
\end{array} 
\right),
\ \ \
& R_{z}\left(\theta\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta&\sin\theta&0 \\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{array}$%
} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\resizebox{.915\hsize}{!}{%
\begin{array}{ccc}` will generate an error but not the one you show, as `array` can only be used in math mode. please fix your example so it is a complete document that can be run to see the error.

Comment: it's usually recommended not to scale text in this way as it will result in very irregular font sizes

Comment: this is not a texstudio error, please change the title.

Comment: the error report by your example is not th eone you state but `Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete.`  which is because you do not have the `{article}` option on your `\documentclass`

Comment: if I add `{article}` then the error is `! LaTeX Error: File '_twoopt.sty' not found.` do you really have a package of that name starting with an underscore? Then there is an error that `_EuroMasterDiss_sty.sty` is missing, then finally there is the error predicted in the first comment about a missing `$` if all those errors are ignored it gets to the end without  generating the error message in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the article back in when I edited it such that it would work elsewhere; I have to use a specific template that comes with the relevant style sheets etc The weird file names are not my doing! So I get a missing $ error that comes coupled with the "File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd." error and it's since that started that the document won't compile anymore. I couldn't find any missing $ anyway...

Comment: You need to check the document _as posted_.  Do what you are asking other people to do: copy the above code into a new file in a new folder and run it through latex. Do you get the error that you are asking about? As I said in the initial comment the error about `$` is because `\begin{array}`  needs to be in math mode, eg surrounded by `$` but (much) better would be not to put it in the `\resizebox`

Comment: Ah! I thought that anything between \begin{equation}...\end{equation} was in math mode. Does \resizebox negate this? I will post the working script for future users in a third edit. THANK YOU!

Comment: Please don't post solutions in questions. Either post an answer or ask @DavidCarlisle to answer, if that's possible. Your document class options make no sense with `article`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\resizebox{.915\hsize}{!}{%
\begin{array}{ccc}
```

will generate an error but not the one you show, as array can only be used in math mode